Two vectors with same numbers in different order
Consider these two vectors of real numbers with the same length
$$
a\equiv (1,1,2,3,3,1)
$$
$$
b\equiv (1,3,1,3,2,1)
$$
The two vectors have the same numbers, although in different orders. Is there a more technical and formal way to describe what is common between $a$ and $b$?

You already added the tag "permutations".

You can say, depending on taste, that $a$ and $b$

"are equivalent up to permutation (of the coordinates),"
"are permutations of each other,"
"are in the same orbit of the permutation action on coordinates" (technically correct but unnecessarily wordy; I mention this because in various generalizations of this idea sometimes it is necessary to use this language),
"have the same multiset of entries" (technically correct but very unusual, we almost never explicitly discuss multisets in mathematics),
"have the same entries with multiplicity" (much more common than multiset language and often used e.g. in the context of eigenvalues).

I would pick option 1 with no further context but option 5 would be standard in some contexts. "Up to" is standard terminology here; it has the semi-technical meaning of referring to being equivalent with respect to an equivalence relation. Also, note that $a$ and $b$ don't have to have entries that are numbers and they could be members of an arbitrary set.
